# Use of flag in c?

Tags: c

I am the beginners of programming so,i don't know the use flag in c.since ,i have searched many question about flag in c but i don't get it.i request you to answer my question to you developers thank you.

Comment: Are talking about a command line flag to gcc/clang/etc. ?? Or are you wanting to implement a program in C that accepts flags?

Answer (score 3):

A "flag" variable is simply a boolean variable whose contents is "true" or "false".

You can use either the `bool` type with `true` or `false`, or an integer variable with zero for "false" and non-zero for "true".

Answer (score 1):

So *why* would you use a **flag**?

Suppose you are outputting a byte value in binary, one bit at a time, say decimal `42` which is `00101010`.

But, you don't want any leading zeros, and the output should be `1010101`.

You can use a **flag** to tell you whether to suppress the `0` bits. Start with the flag as `true`, and whenever you output a `1` bit you set the flag to `false`, telling you not to suppress `0` bits any more.

Of course, the final bit needs to be output even if all bits are `0`, but that's another matter.